# Using LINQ to make a dictionary from Request.Form.AllKeys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, model-binding, formcollection

So I have a page with inputs made specifically to model bind to a dictionary. Like the example below.

```
"person[0].Key"    "Tom" 
"person[0].Value"  "cat" 
"person[1].Key"    "Jerry" 
"person[1].Value"  "mouse"
```

So using .Net MVC this will bind to the dictionary like I want it to. However I need to replicate this behavior in old aspx page's helper method. So I thought about just parsing the Form Collection myself and creating a dictionary from it. Something similar to this (I know it's not quite right):

```
var people = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(n => n.StartsWith("person"));
var x = people .Zip(Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(n => n.StartsWith("person")).Skip(1), (key, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
```

However this seems a little hacky and it only works off order and not off the actual naming convention of Key and Value.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Either via LINQ or with access to the model binder.

Comment: ASP.NET is open source. You could have a look how the ModelBinder does its work here: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs Particularly line 722 seems to be what you're looking for.